# Which is fastest: $.each, .ForEach, for-loop or something else?

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop, foreach

I couldn't decide if I should go with *$.each(array, function(){...})* or *array.ForEach(...)* or something else. So I've called the might google that gave me [this link, which is fantastic if it's reliable](http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/251).

According to that, there's a huge difference in speed between different approaches. Also, generally, a *for*-loop seems to be preferred.

I'm not a guru on JavaScript so I'd like to get some input from some JS-savvy members.

Comment: You could always run some tests on jsPerf.com

Comment: @j08691 What's that link in the question?

Comment: @RobW - oh c'mon that link wasn't there a minute ago was it?

Comment: @j08691 Assuming lazy donkey question much?  :D   (I do forget to do the proper research on occasion but this time - rock solid, haha.)

Comment: @Kay How did you know there was a newer version? Also, how did you get to it? I just went to the original but couldn't find a "most recent"-link...

Comment: The downvoter: care to comment so I can correct the question?

Comment: @KonradViltersten I edited the version you supplied by appending "/edit" to the URL and decreased the Array size. To find other versions just scroll down in the fiddle. I cannot tell which version is the best™ though. :)

Comment: @Kay Thanks. That was very informative site I've found. I just can't believe that I got down-voted and close-suggested... Did I express myself poorly?!

Comment: After just reviewing this question, I don't see an actual problem.  Unless you have actual performance issues (none are listed), this looks to me to be [a sad tragedy of micro-optimization.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html).

Comment: @ErikPhilips My question should be seen as an academic wondering. I don't have any practical performance problem (yet, at least). Driven by pure curiosity for the language, I browsed for different iterator approaches and stumbled across the **vastly** different bench-marks. Then I got intrigued and asked for in-depth discussion on the subject from those who know JS better than me. So it's rather **a sad tragedy of not having a wife/kids**, looking for something to do with my time. I rather get to know JS better than sit and stare at the TV.   :)

Comment: I mentioned this because the second sentence in [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) is *you should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.*.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Valid point. There should be a way to tag a question as an open-type, what-do-others-think, speculative, soft-valued wondering. Especially when it comes to coding style and general approaches and strategies that aren't specifically related to a technical issue. Or am I a lone wolf when it comes to improving for the sake of improvement alone?   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten Checkout http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When comparing Jquery loops to javascript loops you need to remember Jquery is implemented using javascript.

All Jquery functions eventually end up running standard javascript code.

As such this means that in most cases native javascript will be more efficient.

My prefered loop for speed is:

```
for(var i, ilen = MAXLENGTH; i < ilen; i++){
}
```

That is unless iterating through a javascript object in which case:

```
for(var key in object){
     if(object.hasOwnProperty(key)){

     }
}
```

This stands for the majority of use cases when comparing Jquery to javascript.

```
$('#elementid');
```

is much slower than

```
$(document.getElementById('elementId'));
```

along with a multitude of other examples.

Jquery can be used to make code look cleaner or for cross browser compatibility pre-version 2.

However in high performance situations if you can guarantee you only need to support modern browsers javascript is generally much quicker.

Comment: Comparing `$(selector)` to `$.each` is not really relevant considering that `$.each` is a glorified `for` loop while the selector kicks off a parse and then search.

Comment: @pickypg: I believe SlitCanvas is facilitating the jQuery is almost always slower (in whatever scenario) than native javascript just because it's performing checksums and adds overhead to any operation.

Comment: Yes, Brad is correct. Although I love Jquery for it's ease of use and cross-browser support. I've found doing things the old fashioned way can be much quicker and more efficient.

Comment: I'd agree for the general case, but I would disagree in the case of `$.each`. There is overhead, for sure, as it checks to verify that the passed in object "`isArrayLike`", but it executes a raw `for` loop from there.  For raw speed, there is no question, but in the general case when it's not really the bottleneck, I would question the presumption that JQuery is slow and therefore unworthy except when compatibility is necessary.  Taking a peak at the JQuery implementation, they internally will do the best loop above as suggested (the bit of overhead), which I'd suggest pays for itself.

Comment: While I agree for a standard HTML page no noticable difference will ever be seen between the two. Looking at the Jsperf link included in the question above shows the scary reality of Jquery vs javascript. And as for browser compatibility on for loops. In the case of basic loops I hope Jquery isn't needed for compatibility.

Answer (score 14):

Probably the native for loop (well, everywhere except opera, where foreach is faster but that's another story).

However **it really doesn't matter in 99.9% of cases**.

Always prefer readable code over faster code when you can. All of these types of loops can handle hundreds of thousands of iterations every second on an average machine.

Readable code is much more important here - if a `$.each` over 100 elements seems more readable to you - by all means do that (I personally usually prefer `Array.forEach`, mainly because it's native and consistent with native `.map` `.filter` `.reduce` and so on). If you're performing a lot of work in the loop the difference becomes even smaller.

Lets say you have a method called doSomethingWithCurrent:

```
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
   var current = elements[i];
   doSomethingWithCurrent(current);
}
```

Vs:

```
elements.forEach(doSomethingWithCurrent);
```

The second is probably slower, but it's also a lot more readable (at least to me) which makes it more maintainable.

What about the following scenario - you have an array of objects with first and last names and you want to create a new array of strings containing the full name:

Plain loop:

```
var new = [];
for(var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
    new.push(names[i].firstName+" "+names[i].lastName);
}
```

Using map:

```
var new = names.map(function(elem){ 
    return elem.firstName+" "+elem.lastName;
});
```

Again, I find the second more readable, even if it's slower. Writing maintainable and readable code is often more important than writing fast code.

That said, "what's more readable" is often a matter of personal taste, it's important to stay consistent.

For desert - have some Knuth:

> Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.

Comment: I agree with you on the readability issue. I usually follow the convention assumed by the team or implied by the previously deployed code. What stroke me here was the **vast** difference between the methods. I also realize that even the slowest method on my Foxy was waaay quicker than the best on IE. Still, I got a bit chocked. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @KonradViltersten That perf you linked to is pretty well known :) (Especially in more extended versions including a `while` alternative, counting down, etc). These sort of performance questions are more common in the context of nodejs (_after_ finding the bottlenecks of course). In client side JavaScript - the performance of a for loop doesn't matter that much (sometimes in games). Just try sticking an intensive action in it and the overhead of the actual loop will disappear fast. Convention of the team is definitely the way to go :) I'm not saying don't optimize, but optimize when you must.

Comment: Wise words, Benjamin. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to JavaScript, I am often torn between raw speed and knowing that the function exists.

According to Mozilla, [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is not supported in IE until IE9.

As such, I would pretty much avoid it in favor of normal `for` loops as JSPerf shows to run much faster in Chrome (at least), or good old `$.each` from JQuery because you can rely on the fact that it's there and it will most likely start using `Array.forEach` internally at some point anyway.

Comment: It's perfectly legitimate to shim language features that were already implemented. I often shim things like `forEach`, `map` and `filter` when dealing with code that has to support older browsers.

Comment: I completely agree with that. I also shim `Array.indexOf` and `String.trim` in favor of `$.trim` due mostly to readability.