# EJS - Standard For/While vs forEach(function() {

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

When using EJS tempting engine in an Express, Node.js web app, what are the performance differences between a stand for & while loop and its forEach loop?

For Each:

```
forEach(function(user){
    // code
});
```

Standard while loop:

```
var i = 0;
while (i < users.length) { 
    // code 
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Heavily related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17253554/1233251
Note that loop performance in JavaScript will hardly be different just because they're in a template engine.

Comment: `Array.forEach` is generally slower than a `while` or `for` loop, but it's not something you'll notice unless you're iterating over huge arrays.